# Are temp tables automatically created when referencing to them?

Tags: t-sql, temporary-tables

I came across the following script and I am trying to understand it.

```
select columnA, columnB, columnC
  into #tmpTable
  from tableA
```

The `#tmpTable` is referenced after that query, but not before it. There is not a declaration for `#tmpTable` anywhere in the sql script.

My somewhat general question is:

Will the above create the temp table automatically and why? Is this only for T-SQL or applies generally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not only about Temporary table it's about the `INTO Statement` in Sql Server. The `INTO statement` creates a table in the Database and this table is equal to same table we create with `Create Table` statement.

But this statement does not inherit any `constraints`.

Answer (score 3):

Using your example you are utilising the

```
SELECT ... INTO ... FROM
```

SQL syntax. This syntax creates a new table and insert the resulting rows from the query into the new table.

```
select columnA, columnB, columnC
into #tmpTable
from tableA
```

Using the above example a new table, #tmpTable will be created with the data from coulmnA, columnB and columnC from tableA. The data types in #tmpTable will match the datatypes of tableA.

You can of course create a true physical table and have multiple tables in your select statement.

```
select t1.columnA, t1.columnB, t1.columnC,t2.columnD
into #tmpTable
from tableA t1
join tableB t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

If you do create a table using this syntax then you should be aware that Indexes, Constraints and Triggers are not added to the new table.